# Capturar datos desde Modal con PHP y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7

Tengo una modal que es para modificar los datos de un usuario, sin embargo no se como traerlos desde la base

este es mi código de la Modal

```
<!-- Modal para Modificar -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="EditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="defaultModalLabel">Editar Usuario</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="editar_usuario.php?id_user = <?php echo $_GET['user']; ?> "  method="GET">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus value="<?php echo $user; ?> " >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="material-icons">lock</i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" minlength="6" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect">Actualizar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Y este es el código utilizado que he hecho para poder capturar los datos

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

if( isset($_GET['id_user']) ){

    $id_user = $_GET['id_user'];
    $user = $_GET['user'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_user = '$id_user' and user = '$user' ";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    if ( mysqli_num_rows($resultado)== 1 ){
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
     $user = $row['user'];

    }


}


?>
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo solucionarlo para poder traer la información a esa modal, y posteriormente a ello poder actualizar los datos

Comment: Supongo que tu archvio donde tienes el modal es usuarios.php y la linea 196 es donde pone  name="user" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus value="<?php echo $user.  Si es así por lo que se ve en el código es que no tienes definida esa variable por ningún lado. Si antes del form has hecho un query para recuperar el usuario asegúrate que has inicializado esa variable